# Eisenstein criteria in k(t)[X]

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, function-fields

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $\ne 2$ and $L$ be a finite extension of the function field $k(t)$ in which $\sqrt{t}$ and $\sqrt{1+t}$ exist.

> Find the minimal polynomial of $T:=\sqrt{t}+\sqrt[]{1+t}$.

Some calculations show that $P(T)=0$ where $P(T):= T^4-2(2t+1)T^2+1$.

I am trying to use Eisenstein criterion to prove that P is irreducible over $k(t)[X]$.

Since the constant coefficient of $P(T)$ is $1$, I can't apply Eisenstein criterion, so I computed $P(T+1)=T^4+4T^3+4(1-t)T^2-8tT-(4t+1)$ and I still have a problem with the constant term.

Thank you for any help or hints to prove irreducibility of P over $k(t)$ even without Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: You can show $X^2-(1+t)$ and $X^2-t$ are irreducible over $k(t)$ and $k(t,\sqrt{1+t})$ using Eisenstein criterion, it implies $((X-\sqrt{t})^2-(1+t))((X+\sqrt{t})^2-(1+t))$ is irreducible over $k(t)$

Comment: This fails in characteristic $2$. Otherwise, one can prove that $T$ has four distinct conjugates using Kummer theory.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you I added char (k) $\ne 2$.

Comment: @reuns, Thank you, where does the last implication come from? if $X^2-(1+t)$ is irreducible over $k(t)$ and $X^2-t$ irreducible over $k(t,\sqrt{1+t})$ why is that $P$ irreducible over $k(t)$? From your factorisation of $P$, do we need to show that the four roots $\pm\sqrt[]{1+t} \pm\sqrt[] t$ are not in $k(t)$?

Comment: Because then all the $\pm \sqrt{t}\pm \sqrt{1+t}$ are $k(t)$-conjugate

Comment: I see now, Thank you!

Comment: @reuns, I am trying to summerize your idea: if all the roots of $P$ are conjugates then P is irreducible over $k(t)$. is that correct? I'm sure I am still missing something because there is a counter-example: $P=X^4-9$.

Comment: It is not a counter-example. A polynomial $\prod_j (X-a_j)\in F[X]$ with distinct roots is irreducible iff all the $a_j$ are $F$-conjugate to $a_1$

Comment: You don't need Eisenstein's criterion or Galois theory for this. Just argue that if $P$ was not irreducible, then it would have a degree-$1$ or degree-$2$ factor; thus, $1, T, T^2$ would be linearly dependent over $k\left(t\right)$. This would easily yield a $k\left(t\right)$-linear dependence between $1, \sqrt{t}, \sqrt{1+t}, \sqrt{t\left(1+t\right)}$. Renaming $\sqrt{t}$ as $s$, this would mean a $k\left(s^2\right)$-linear dependence between $1, s, \sqrt{1+s^2}, s\sqrt{1+s^2}$. And this could be rewritten as a $k\left(s\right)$-linear dependence between $1$ and $\sqrt{1+s^2}$. This ...

Comment: ... would mean that $1+s^2$ is a square in $k\left(s\right)$. But it is not, for the same reason as why $\sqrt 2$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Could you please detail why $1, \sqrt{t}, \sqrt{1+t}, \sqrt{t\left(1+t\right)}$ are $k(t)$ linearly dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on reuns'comments as it might be helpful to someone and I hope it is error-free:

- $1+t$ is irreducible over $k[t]$ as it is of degree 1 and it verifies $(1+t)\ |-(1+t)$ and $(1+t) \nmid 1$. By Eisenstein criterion, $X^2-(1+t)$ is irreducible over $k(t)$.
- $t=(\sqrt[]{t+1})^2-1=(\sqrt[]{t+1}-1)(\sqrt[]{t+1}+1)$ and 
  $(\sqrt[]{t+1}+1) $ is  irreducible over $k[t,\sqrt[]{t+1}]$ and $(\sqrt[]{t+1}+1) \nmid 1$ so  By Eisenstein criterion, $X^2-t$ is irreducible over $k(t,\sqrt[]{t+1})$.

We deduce that $\pm \sqrt[]t \pm \sqrt[]{t+1}$ are conjugates over $k(t)$ and that 
$X^4-2(2t+1)+1=((X-\sqrt{t})^2-(1+t))((X+\sqrt{t})^2-(1+t))$ is irreducible over $k(t)$.